# Adding a method to a Typescript class using prototype

Tags: typescript, prototype

[image]

I don't seem to be able to add a method to my Typescript class using prototype. Visual Studio warns me that the function does not exist in the the target type.

I read something about declaring an additional interface for my type that would include the definition of the method I want to add, but it's not very clear to me how I should do this after importing my type with `import`. In fact, I cannot simply do:

```
import { EcommerceCartItem } from "../classes/EcommerceCartItem";

interface EcommerceCartItem {
    myMethod: any
}

EcommerceCartItem.prototype.myMethod = function () {
    return null;
};
```

...because the import declaration conflicts with the local declaration of `EcommerceCartItem`. So how should I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must declare the interface in the appropriate module for it to count as an augmentation:

```
import { EcommerceCartItem } from "../classes/EcommerceCartItem";
declare module "../classes/EcommerceCartItem" {
    interface EcommerceCartItem {
        myMethod: any
    }
}

EcommerceCartItem.prototype.myMethod = function () {
    return null;
};
```

Comment: Oh, amazing, I didn't know this syntax. Thank you very much.